How to solve an equation from a string in an array?
I'm creating a quiz project for my year 13 coursework and am working on a multiple choice form. I have questions stored in a 2D array where for every question there is a potential of 4 answers.
I want to know how to convert the string that holds the equation into an integer that can be solved for a correct answer. When trying to simply CInt the string that holds the question, I got System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "4x4" to type 'Integer' is not valid' error.
Questions(0) = "2x2"
Questions(1) = "4x4"
Questions(2) = "6x8 "
Questions(3) = "5x3"
Questions(4) = "10x10"

Dim question As String = Questions(value)
Dim answer As Integer = CInt(question)  'this is the line I get the error
Dim UserAnswer As String

If UserAnswer = answer Then
    UsersMarks = UsersMarks + 1 'increment
End If
Accuracy = (UsersMarks / TotalMarks) * 100
lblAccuracy.Text = Accuracy & "%"
TotalMarks = TotalMarks + 1 'increment
lblMarks.Text = UsersMarks & " / " & TotalMarks
If TotalMarks = 5 Then
    Me.Hide()
    Summary.Show()
End If

Any help would be appreciated as I'm really not sure how to solve it.

Well, of course this gives an error, because CInt is not an evaluator for mathematical expressions.

If all your questions follow the pattern "x" you could "Split" the question string using "x" as the delimiter and then using "CInt" on both "" strings and calculate the answer yourself.
